# How can I make breakpoints work when debugging Zend Framework in Komodo IDE 7?

Tags: php, debug, zend, komodo

I am trying to use Komodo IDE 7 (7.1.3) to debug a Zend Framework (PHP) project. The project is being served by Apache on a Ubuntu Server and I am using Komodo on Windows 7 on the same LAN. The files are on a mapped drive corresponding to the root folder of the web project.

When I start the Zend Framework debugging, by loading a page with Chrome's Xdebug Helper activated, Komodo will warn me about a debugging session being started and correctly load the index.php file that starts the Zend Framework (and loads the bootstrap). However it does not stop on breakpoints, in any file. If I step into/over function calls it can go into files (although it complains about URI mapping and opens files in read-only) but it doesn't stop on breakpoints.

What am I missing in the configuration for it to stop on breakpoints? Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting in the ActiveState Komodo Support forums I followed instructions to add proper URI mappings to Komodo IDE's configuration. After reading the documentation I thought Komodo would pick it up automatically but once I set up a URI mapping for each main directory (e.g. controllers, views, models ans so forth) it was working flawlessly.

For more information, see the thread at http://support.activestate.com/node/9261.

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugger connection preferences to change the port that Komodo listens to from the default value of 9000 to one of the following:

- 8080
- the port your remote host or local host is using
- [a free port or a proxy](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/7.0/prefs.html#DebuggerConnection)

Comment: I have posted an answer - the problem was the lack of URI mapping.